# ¿Cuál es la forma más eficiente para obtener el tamaño de archivo subido en Go?

Tags: go

Tengo un servidor de web, muy simple, en Go, y en una página hay un formulario para subir un archivo:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"><br>
    Description: <input type="text" name="descr"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Y leo el archivo en Go así:

```
func imageUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    _,imageHead,err := r.FormFile("image")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error with upload: %s", err)
        return
    }
    imageDesc := r.FormValue("descr")

    fileSize := .... ???

    log.Printf("Recibí %s <%s> (%d bytes)", imageHead.Filename, imageDesc, fileSize)
}
```

Pero qué hago para obtener `fileSize`?

`imageData` es un [multipart.File](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File), que expone io.Reader, io.ReaderAt, io.Seeker y io.Closer. Pero ¿no archivo directamente? Así, la única opción es leer el io.Reader para ver cuantos bytes tengo?  ¿O hay otra opción más eficiente?

Comment: ¿Tu objetivo es limitar el tamaño del archivo o solo conocer la forma de obtener el tamaño?

Comment: @CésarBustíos: Solo saber el tamaño.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La única forma confiable para obtener el tamaño exacto del archivo seria leerlo todo para contar los bytes. Una posible manera sería usando [io.ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull).

De otro modo esa información podría enviarla el cliente explicitamente en alguna cabecera del request, pero aquí dependerías del compromiso del cliente en enviar siempre esta información.

Adicionalmente, podría ser prudente utilizar algo como [io.LimitReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader) para leer hasta un cierto límite.

Answer (score 3):

1- Si no vas a copiar el archivo al servidor podrías obtener el tamaño del archivo mediante js y asignar el valor a un hidden input y leerlo junto con la carga del archivo.

2- Si vas a copiar el archivo al server entonces deberás crear un archivo (os.File), del cual puedes leer su tamaño después de haber copiado el contenido, en tu codigo no estás haciendo nada con el contenido del archivo, si vas a copiarlo al servidor necesitas leer el contenido:

```
func imageUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    data, imageHead,err := r.FormFile("image")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error with upload: %s", err)
        return
    }
    imageDesc := r.FormValue("descr")

    out, err := os.Create("myfiles/"+imageHead.Filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error creando archivo, verifique con el administrador sus permisos!")
        return
    }
    defer out.Close()
    // Copiando el contenido al archivo
    // size1 es el tamaño del archivo en bytes
    // puedes ocupar este valor
    size1, err = io.Copy(out, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %v\n", err.Error())
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
        return
    }

    //o obtenerlo tambien con Stat() y Size()
    var fileSize int64
    fileStat, err := out.Stat()
    if err == nil {
        fileSize = fileStat.Size()
    }



    log.Printf("Recibí %s <%s> (%d bytes)", imageHead.Filename, imageDesc, fileSize)
}
```